# Exact syntax for associating a commit with a work item

Tags: git, tfs

When working with Microsoft Team Foundation Server and Git, it is possible to associate a commit with a work item either using the UI Visual Studio provides, or by adding the work item ID in the commit message like #4711.

Now I noted that this does not always get recognized by TFS.

These work:

```
bla #4711

bla: #4711, #4712

bla #4711, #4712.

bla #4711! ,#4712
```

These do not work:

```
bla (#4711)

bla (#4711, #4712)

bla 4711

bla [#4711]

bla (#4711 #4711_ _#4711

bla a#4711
```

Instead of hoping that I will do it right in the future, I’d somehow prefer to know the conditions when TFS recognizes a work item. What are these conditions, what is the syntax, the regex used?

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/4038344-associate-a-git-commit-with-a-work-item) does mention (from a TFS Program Manager)

> From the Pending Changes window, work items can be added using the UI features or by adding a mention to the commit comment in the form of “`#ID`” where ID is the work item ID.

So the regex detecting that syntax does not seem to include anything else surrounding that number.
As in `\b#\d+\b` ([word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)): that would explain why `(#xxx)` does not work.

Comment: Thank you. `(#4711)` does not work, so I think the regex includes some context...

Comment: @Martin yes, I meant the regex is probably `\b#\d+\b`

Comment: Yes, maybe something similar like this. Please note that `\b#\d+\b` would match in `a#4711` and `a#4711)` - please as well see my edit.